# How to reject symbols in EditText widget (Android) after some amount of them was entered?

Tags: android, text, edit

I'd like to watch out for the amount of the symbols in EditText. 
To do this, I use

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

```
            int symbolRemains = 140 - edTextSMS.getText().length();
            if (symbolRemains>=0) {
                                 tvSymbolsRemains.setText("Осталось символов:"+symbolRemains);
                                   }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Максимум 140 символов в сообщении", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }


                                                                                     }
    });
```

So, in my ELSE section I'd like to reject the entering symbols. Of course, simple "return" doesn't work. How can I do this ?

Thanks$)

Comment: Keep in mind that in some input methods such as Cangjie (for Chinese), users have to type in a few characters to get one character typed. For example, we type `十` `弓` `木` `(space)` to get the character `字` inputted, but the `弓` `木` may report as new characters as well, depending on the IME. As a result, the user cannot type the 139th character because he has to type to 141 so as to get 139 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(s);
buffer.delete(start, start + count);
edTextSMS.setText(buffer.toString());
```

if you want to limit your `EditText` to 140 characters.

**Updated with gabi's suggestion.**

Comment: but the user may want to add the 141'th character inside the string, not at the end...

Answer (score 0):

add a text watcher on our edit text and if the max limit was reached, delete the entered character in method onTextChanged (I think you must delete characters from start to start + count, start and count being parameters for this method).